# Import fiona fails

Tags: python, import, package, anaconda

I installed `fiona` using `conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/ioos fiona`. Then `import fiona` gives the following error message

```
import fiona
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgif.4.1.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/libgdal.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I would like to understand this error message and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you install gdal? the doc says "Fiona requires Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4 and GDAL/OGR 1.8+"

Comment: I didn't, but would this suffice? ```conda search gdal
Fetching package metadata: ....
gdal                         1.10.1                   py27_0  defaults
                             1.10.1                   py33_1  defaults
                             1.10.1                   py27_1  defaults
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure, you can check if libgdal already exists. check if `/usr/local/lib/libgif.4.1.6.dylib` exists also